# Problem when editing individual product images upload

Tags: magento-1.9, product, image, ce-1.9.2.3

**PROBLEM**:
In Magento admin while adding products image is not uploading. I tried by uploading in different browsers but it too doesn't worked. I have given 777 file permissions to media folder. When I upload image, image is stored in `media/tmp/catalog/media` folder. Magento redirect to the login page and does not save the info.

We are using Magento version 1.9.2.3. It happened in product edit time.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Look into the var/log/exception.log, or enable developer mode; redirection to dashboard sometimes means that an exception is thrown and an error occurs.

Comment: in exception log is clear there are no error showing.

Comment: Is logging enabled? Also, you might want to look into the system.log and webserver (e.g. apache) error log

Comment: Yes logging is enabled

Comment: i have check system.log and apache error log but there are no error found

Comment: It could be that an ajax request fails; try to open the "Network"-tab in Firebug or Chrome Developer Tools, monitor the request and hit "ESC" as soon as you notice the browser is loading a new page. You will then be able to look at the ajax-response

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38373/discussion-between-pushpendra-singh-and-simonthesorcerer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved problem by set cookie life time 3600. previously it set to 0 then it's not working. Thanks @simonthesorcerer for guide me.